# Android Studio: Share file to Messenger using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, messenger

How do I share a file to Messenger with the Facebook SDK.

For some reason when I get to the Share to Messenger dialog window, it stays for a few seconds and the closes. Why is that?

```
 String sayWhat = "This is what you sound like when you write to me, thanks to the app Messenger Say it! Available now at Google Play";
    HashMap hashmap = new HashMap();
    hashmap.put("utteranceId", sayWhat);
    String location = (new StringBuilder(this.getFilesDir().toString())).append(name).append(".wav").toString();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(location);
 ttsread.synthesizeToFile(sayWhat, hashmap, location);
    ShareLinkContent.Builder shareLinkContentBuilder = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().
            setContentDescription("Share with friends").setContentTitle("Messenger SAY IT").setContentUrl(uri);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog(this);
    messageDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
    });
    messageDialog.show(shareLinkContentBuilder.build());
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any errors in logcat? what SDK version are you using? have you tried the latest SDK with one of the sample projects bundled with the SDK? e.g. RPS sample implement an [example](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/dcb746a7b2785bc91ed1ad703762dd0e53579eb1/samples/RPSSample/src/com/example/rps/RpsFragment.java#L423-L438).

Comment: I am using the latest SDK and I have not tried the samples

Answer (score 0):

It was because Facebook Messenger wasn't installed on the device. 
Calling the web function doesn't seem to work from Android 6.0 api 23.

Comment: The messenger app is installed and since I updated to Marshmallow it work